# pandas to_excel TypeError: Unsupported type <type 'list'> in write()

Tags: excel, pandas

I have a dataframe and I am trying to export it in excel. I am using the following code:

```
outcome = merge(sql, emptydf, on='sku', how='left')

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('casafina_json.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
outcome.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

when I run it I get this error:

```
raise TypeError("Unsupported type %s in write()" % type(token))

TypeError: Unsupported type <type 'list'> in write()
```

what's wrong? thanks.

EDIT:
the column on which the two dataframes were joint does not have unique values. I think this may be the cause of the error. Any idea on how to join them differently?

Comment: Seems you have lists as items in the dataframe. Is that the case? If so, see if you can remove them (or just converting to strings with `astype(str)`)

Comment: no there are only datetime64[ns] object float64 int64

Comment: Can you then provide a reproducible example? (and BTW, the object dtypes column can hold lists)

Comment: That error message comes from the pandas Excel writer XlsxWriter. It is due to the issue that @joris suggested: the dataframe data contains an embedded list.

Comment: Have you tried with other engines? Like: openpyxlor or xlwt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know what is wrong. However, it is possible to create a csv out of it with the function:

```
outcome.to_csv('/Users/whatever/whatever.csv')
```